# Conformation window on delete in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

how to make a conformation on boundfield in gridview in delete ....event

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers: Please check the Tags.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to add confirmation on deleting in your grid, correct?
Here is a simple example of grid:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" 
    <Columns>                    
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
                CommandName="Delete"  
                OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure?");'  
                Text="Delete" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <!-- your bound fields here -->

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The trick is in adding client-side confirm to the `OnClientClick` property of the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```
<asp:linkbutton id="btnDelete" runat="server" commandname="Delete" onclientclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');"
        text="Delete" />
```